# Dispose window without shutting down whole program

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

I'm back again :P I have this program that opens up a window. There's options menu that opens in a new window and what I want to happen is when I close the options window, it doesn't shut the program down.
I know that

```
setDefaultCloseOperation();
```

Will close down my window but I looked at the documentation and it doesn't have a solution for my problem. Can anyone be kind enough to help?
Thanks (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// different close actions are available, that do different things!
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

But see also, [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  Sneak preview, the answer is: **Bad (bad, bad) practice.**

> ..(will) look into other window managers

It is not so much 'window' managers we need here as 'view' managers.  Those views (e.g. each in a panel) might then be managed by dialogs, option panes, pop-ups, tool bars, layout managers, (very rarely) other frames or windows..

The content you mention seems well suited to being displayed in a (possibly modal) dialog.

Comment: Huh ok ill look into other window managers, thanks for all the tips